# Compare two text columns to find partial match and new rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two lists of messages. The first one is short messages and the second one is a master file which has longer texts which includes the short messages in the first list but also has many new messages. I want to find the new ones in master file (second list) which has no partial matches.

[image]

something like above. then NO means they are new errors

I tried =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",C:C,1,0)),"No","Yes") but it is other way around. it will find short messages within master file with big messages. I want to check big messages which have the short messages inside compare with the list with short messages and if there is no (partial) match label it as new.

Comment: It s hard to read what you do mean. It is unclear which column `C:C` is, when looking at the picture...    If `list1` is column A, and `list 2` is column B, would this function do what you want: `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(A2;B2)),"no","yes")` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, currently can't test it though

```
=if(sumproduct(--isnumber(search($a$2:$a$8,b2)))>0,"YES","NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&$A$2:$A$8&" "," "&B2& " "))),"YES","NO")
```

*Note the use of spaces otherwise  `aaa` would be found in `kkaaa`*

[image]